# Angular ngCookies $cookie is undefined

Tags: angularjs, django, post, csrf

I am working on a Django-Angular application, and need to make it so csrf token are in all Angular AJAX post or put requests. I am using ngCookies, but when I try to assign the cookies csrf token to all angular post headers, it is giving me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrftoken' of undefined
```

$cookieStore is also undefined, and using get methods on $cookies is not working either. I am loading the right script for angular-cookies, that matches my version of angular, and I am not getting any errors about ngCookies itself, so I am not really sure what it could be ?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

Config.$inject = ["$locationProvider", "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$httpProvider"];
angular
    .module('app.guest', [
        'app.common',
        'app.core',
        'app.repo',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ngCookies'
    ])
    .config(Config);
    .run(['$cookies'], function ($rootScope, $http, $cookies) {
            // set the CSRF token here
            $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
        })

/** ngInject */
function Config($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $cookies) {

    broadcastReady.$inject = ["CommonService", "CommonEvents"];
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
```

console

```
vendor.js:12275 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.guest due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrftoken' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"$cookies"` at the end of your `$inject` list:

```
Config.$inject = ["$locationProvider", "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$httpProvider", "$cookies"];
```

Make sure you load `angular-cookies.js` too.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I guess you can't inject services into the modules configuration, you have to inject it into the modules run block. Even after doing that though, it still comes up as undefined.

Comment: Ah I did not realize you were running that inside a `config()` and what you're trying to do is add `X-CSRFToken` to your POST headers. In which case setting `xsrfCookeName` and `xsrfHeaderName` should suffice and you don't need to explicitly set the cookie in `headers.post`

Comment: Ahhhh so when I set $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'; that will already set the cookie value to any post header ?

Comment: I see what I did, I guess the services you inject with bracket notation has to match the service parameters that are passed into the function. Since run had $rootscope, and $http, but they weren't being passed into the injector, than $cookie wasn't even considered by the run block.

Comment: Yes setting `xsrfCookieName` and `xsrfHeaderName` in your `config()` should do that automatically. No need to explicitly set in `headers.post`.

Comment: `['$cookies']` and then `function ($rootScope, $http, $cookies)` meant that the `$cookies` object was injected as `$rootScope` in your function. Your `$http` and `$cookies` are undefined. You should have used: `['$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies']`.